# wcf Service with net.msmq binding is not picking up messages from the local queue

Tags: iis, msmq

I am having a client app drop the message into a private queue named MsmqService/MsmqService.svc.

In IIS Under default web site,I added the wcf service with the net.msmq binding.

I made sure the queue was set to transactional

The following is the relevant config portion on both the client app and wcf.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="MsmqBindingNonTransactionalNoSecurity" exactlyOnce="false">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="MsmqBindingNonTransactionalTransportSecurity" exactlyOnce="false">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="MsmqBindingTransactionalTransportSecurity" exactlyOnce="true" receiveErrorHandling="Move">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="MsmqService.MsmqService">
        <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/MsmqService/MsmqService.svc" binding="netMsmqBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="MsmqBindingTransactionalTransportSecurity" contract="MsmqContract.IMsmqContract"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I had the net.msmq under enabled protocols for the default web site and under enabled protocols for the wcf service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you are using IIS to host the service. IIS unloads the worker process during periods of inactivity which means there will be no process available to consume a message when one arrives.

To host in IIS is [compliated at best](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1399280/569662). Better to host in a windows service, much simpler.

Comment: Yeah I was easily able to get a windows service version of my requirement working. 
If possible I would like to get the IIS version working as well. The reason is my supervisor feels using windows service is the old style which requires both the client and service to actually read from and write to the queue. Whereas in the IIS style, all this is under the hood and it looks like the client is making a regular wcf call, while in the background Windows process activation service invokes the appropriate method in the wcf service on behalf of the client

Comment: How do you awaken the worker process? I tried selecting browse on the svc file in IIS manager but it makes no difference.
Or is it possible to do the traditional wcf style method invoking  in a windows service INSTEAD of just having an all purpose listener which listens for messages and decides what method to call based on the message

Comment: Ok sorry to harp on the same point, but are you saying that using IIS in this case is point blank the lesser of the two approaches or that isnt worth the trouble?

Comment: There are good reasons for using IIS. Load balancing requests, setting up SPN's etc. But if you just need a hosting container for a msmq listenner then windows services are just less of a headache.

Comment: There's a bunch of stuff here to check: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/a1df55c4-e642-442a-9057-f0aec278d10c/